# AngularJS - Returning value from async http request

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I need to get valid access token so I created a function for that

```
getValidAccessToken(){
    /*
    SOME CODE ...
    */

    if(!expired){
        return accessToken
    }
    else{
        // AJAX call for new token
        // return accessToken containing new token 
    }

}
```

So when I call getValidAccessToken() I want to get accessToken (current one or new one that will come from AJAX call)

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. Try something and come latter with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use promises.  In Angular, this is best done with the [`$q` service provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).  You need to create a promise, and then return it from the method.  Then in the method, resolve or reject the promise.

```
getValidAccessToken(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    /*
    SOME CODE ...
    */

    if(!expired){
        deferred.resolve(accessToken);
    }
    else{
        // AJAX call for new token
        $http.get('/some/url/accessToken')
            .success(function(data) {
                // return accessToken containing new token 
                deferred.resolve(data.accessToken);
            }).
            .error(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
    }

    return deferred;
}
```

Then, in the code that uses this method, call a method when the promise is resolved or rejected:

```
var tokenCall = getValidAccessToken();
tokenCall.then(function(token) {
    // Use the token somehow
}, function(error) {
    // Crap. There was an error.
});
```